# Windows dual boot options (i.e., have to select either D or C partition upon bootup)

Tags: windows-vista, boot

I recently acquired some malicious software program that wrecked havoc with my machine (and me).  I could not access any executable programs on my C drive. The Malware also blocked my use of access to internet.  My drive is partitioned into 3 separate drives.  I am utilizing Windows Vista home edition.  Rather than cleaning my entire drive trying to find solution I loaded another copy of Vista onto the D partition so that I could try to get to internet for help in eradicating the malware. I finally did get the information needed to clean up the mess and things returned to normal.  Except for that copy of Vista sitting out on the D Drive which I used for daily backup of data until copying to CD on weekly basis.  When I boot my machine I get option of selecting two copies of Vista for booting.  I then have to select between two copies, one of which is on the C drive and one of which is on the D drive.  How can I clean the D partition of Vista and and eliminate the sign on snag?  Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you want to configure the boot menu, run msconfig.  You can add or remove items from the boot menu as necessary (although it should still log in after 30 seconds regardless.)

Once you remove a given installation from the boot menu, you can delete the installation at any time.

Answer (score 0):

You could also right click on Computer > Manage bypass UAC go to Storage > Disk Management and from there delete the other partition and re-create, or simply just clear it. Tell me if you need more detailing help.

Answer (score 0):

As @The Green Frog said, delete the partition using Disk Management (also found in the control panel's Administrative Tools).  If it still prompts you at boot for a Vista install that no longer exists, look into [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1).  It'll help you remove the boot entry and streamline the boot process.  Removing the extra partition though is critical to reclaim hard drive space and speed up the overall system.  Remember to back up your stuff!